# Sending sms by python scripts

Tags: python

In below program I am trying to send sms to selected numbers . Numbers are selected from a table using sql query which is then store in pr . In a payload ,instead of putting numbers directly I want to use pr one by one to send sms .But in that case it shows number is missing.is there any way to do.

```
import sqlite3

import requests

conn=sqlite3.connect("Face.db")

cmd="select mnumber from peoples where presence=1"

cursor=conn.execute(cmd)

for row in cursor:
pr=int(row[0])


url = "https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/bulk"

payload = "sender_id=FSTSMS & message=good morning & language=english & route=p & numbers=pr"
headers = {
 'authorization': "zg6YJqFs2wCbPGM9H5p4QOiDlSAca7KvIhWrLxNmEX0RoVBdkefWOGmNVHeR9d6lM8Kzn07gQPBhusFU",
 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
 }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
"sender_id=FSTSMS & message=good morning & language=english & route=p & numbers=pr"
```

to this

```
"sender_id=FSTSMS & message=good morning & language=english & route=p & numbers="+pr
```

above should work . 
I noticed that you added pr within the string

Comment: @kundangupta - Consider for upvote and accept the anser :)